# Live charts data from database

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, livecharts

```
 private void MapChart()
    {
        List<double> allValues = new List<double>();
        string day = null;

        if (CON.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            CON.Close();
        }

        CON.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conDB"].ConnectionString;
        CON.Open();
        CMD = new SqlCommand("select * from tblWeeklyAudit", CON);
        RDR = CMD.ExecuteReader();
        while (RDR.Read())
        {
            allValues.Add(Convert.ToDouble(RDR["Defects"]));
            day = Convert.ToString(RDR["Day"]);
        }

        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Values = new ChartValues<double>(allValues)
            }
        };

        Labels = new[] { "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4" };

        DataContext = this;
    }
```

I want to know how to get the values in **day variable** inside this.

```
Labels = new[] { "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4"};
```

Count of no. of days may vary. I'm doing this as my project for my degree.

Comment: Where do you want to get the data from ?

Comment: I want it from the data I have taken the data from DB as string day = Convert.ToString(RDR["Day"]);

Comment: So the value of `RDR["Day"]` might be `Day1` or `Day2` ? In that case, why not add it to your list inside the loop ?

Comment: That will not work isn't it?

Comment: Why do you think, it does not work ? Try like `yourListOfStrings.Add(day);`

Comment: Instead of creating 1 after the other it will overwrite on the same first label

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the value of `RDR["Day"]` for every record inside the datareader to be added to the array/collection and the value of `RDR["Day"]` is something like `Day1` or `Day2` or `DayN` for each record, you can create a list of strings outside your loop and add to that inside your loop.

Similar to what you did in `allValues` list.

```
var dayLabels= new List<string>();
while (RDR.Read())
{
   allValues.Add(Convert.ToDouble(RDR["Defects"]));
   var d= RDR.GetString(RDR.GetOrdinal("Day"));     
   dayLabels.Add(d);
}
```

You can do most of the common operations of array (enumerating through it, getting an item from a specific index etc) with a list as well. If you absolutely want an array from this list, you can call the `ToArray` method on the list to get that

```
var myArray = dayLabels.ToArray();
```

Comment: how do i call to this `Labels = new[] { }` from `dayLabels`? I tried this `Labels = new[] { dayLables.ToString()};` but it didn't work. :(

Comment: See the last line of my code. Do the same thing. `Labels =dayLabels.ToArray();`